# r subset array using vector

Tags: arrays, r, subset

I feel like this question should have already been answered, but I found none.  I have an array and I want to subset it using a vector.  I know how to do it the hard way, but I'm sure there's got to be an easy way.  Any ideas?

Here's my example:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:3], 2), b = rep(letters[1:2], 3), c = c(rep("a", 5), "b"), x = rnorm(6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

l <- by(dat[ , "x"], dat[ , 1:3], mean)

l["a", "a", "a"] # works  
l[c("a", "a", "a")] # does not work
```

So I guess I need to a way to remove the `c()` wrapper form `c("a", "a", "a")` before passing it to `l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a vector you could use a matrix:

```
l[matrix(rep("a", 3), nrow=1)]
```

Comment: Or just transpose the vector, using `t(c("a", "a", "a"))`

Answer (score 4):

This has already been answered, but I wanted to make things a little bit more clear. Let's take your example here:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:3], 2), b = rep(letters[1:2], 3), c = c(rep("a", 
    5), "b"), x = rnorm(6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

l <- by(dat[, "x"], dat[, 1:3], mean)

l["a", "a", "a"]  # works  

## [1] 1.246

l[c("a", "a", "a")]  # does not work

## [1] NA NA NA
```

A previous answer suggested to use `matrix(rep("a", 3), nrow=1)` in subsetting. 
I want to expand on *why* this works. First, let's take a look at what the
differences between these two data structures are:

```
a.mat <- matrix(rep("a", 3), nrow = 1)
a.vec <- c("a", "a", "a")  # Note: this is equivalent to rep('a', 3)
a.mat

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] "a"  "a"  "a"

a.vec

## [1] "a" "a" "a"

as.matrix(a.vec)

##      [,1]
## [1,] "a" 
## [2,] "a" 
## [3,] "a"

l[a.mat]

## [1] 1.246

l[a.vec]

## [1] NA NA NA

l[as.matrix(a.vec)]

## [1] NA NA NA
```

`a.mat` and `a.vec` look the same when you print them to screen, but they are not
treated in the same way because R creates matrices in [Column Major Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order#Column-major_order) in that it writes and reads a matrix column by column. When you use a matrix for subsetting, it will use each column as a different dimension. If the number of columns in the matrix match up with the number of dimensions in the object to be subsetted, it will use each column for each subsequent dimension.

If the number of columns does not match up, R will collapse the matrix into a vector and attempt to match the element indices that way. Here are some more examples:

```
a.mat[, -1]  # Now only two columns

## [1] "a" "a"

l[a.mat[, -1]]  # Notice you get NA twice here.

## [1] NA NA

l[matrix(rep("a", 4), nrow = 1)]  # Using a matrix with 4 columns.

## [1] NA NA NA NA
```

As a side note, when you subset with a character vector, R will attempt to match any element *names*. If they don't exist, you will get an `NA` or an error:

```
# Vector example:
x <- letters
x[1]

## [1] "a"

x["a"]

## [1] NA

names(x) <- letters
x[1]

##   a 
## "a"

x["a"]

##   a 
## "a"

x[c("a", "a", "a")]

##   a   a   a 
## "a" "a" "a"

x[a.mat]  # collapsing matrix down to a vector.

##   a   a   a 
## "a" "a" "a"
# Matrix example:
x <- matrix(letters[1:9], nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
x

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] "a"  "d"  "g" 
## [2,] "b"  "e"  "h" 
## [3,] "c"  "f"  "i"

x[c(1, 1)]

## [1] "a" "a"

x[1, 1]

## [1] "a"

x[c("a", "a")]

## [1] NA NA

x["a", "a"]

## Error: no 'dimnames' attribute for array

rownames(x) <- letters[1:3]
colnames(x) <- letters[1:3]
x

##   a   b   c  
## a "a" "d" "g"
## b "b" "e" "h"
## c "c" "f" "i"

x[c(1, 1)]

## [1] "a" "a"

x[1, 1]

## [1] "a"

x[c("a", "a")]

## [1] NA NA

x["a", "a"]

## [1] "a"
```

And finally, if you use a numeric vector, you will always get a defined value (unless it's out of bounds):

```
l[c(1,1,1)]

## [1] 1.246 1.246 1.246

l[1, 1, 1]

## [1] 1.246
```