# Is there a way to select all elements of a dimension when matrix-indexing a multidimensional array in R?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, subset

I have a multidimensional array, and I (finally) know I can subset it with a matrix, which has as many columns as there are dimensions in the array. But I need to skip a dimension in the process, to get/set not one element of that dimension, but all of them. How to?

```
array5d[matrix(c(3,15,2,7,9),1)]
```

is equivalent to

```
array5d[3,15,2,7,9]
```

but what is the matrix-based equivalent of

```
array5d[ ,15,2,7,9]
```

The goal here is to be able to subset an array with values of a bunch of vectors, that are generated separately. I don't always need to subset with the first dimension left open, this (or rather, these) changes from case to case. I have a very ugly solution with eval(str2lang(paste0(...))), but I would really like a healthier approach

Comment: Please provide full examples including input in reproducible form and expected output.  Please read the information at the top of of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: I asked a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013962/subset-an-array-using-a-vector-of-indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler reproducible example:

```r
array3d <- array(1:27,dim=c(3,3,3))
x <- array3d[,1,1]
```

In the comments @user2957945 points out that setting the 'blank' elements of the index vector to TRUE will allow `do.call('[',...)` to select all of the elements from that dimension.

```r
i <- list(TRUE, 1, 1);  do.call('[', c(list(array3d), i))
```

---

Previous (suboptimal) answer:

I don't know if there's a simpler/better way, but this works without using `str2lang`/`eval`/etc.:

```r
i <- c(NA,1,1)  ## NA denotes "get all elements from this dimension"
getfun <- function(a,i) {
   i <- as.list(i)
   for (j in seq_along(i)) {
     if (all(is.na(i[[j]]))) i[[j]] <- seq(dim(a)[j])
   }
   v <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid,i))
   a[v]
}
getfun(array3d,i)
```

Comment: `i <- list(TRUE, 1, 1);  do.call('[', c(list(array3d), i))` may be more simpler and retains dimensions of slice (from link above)

Comment: @user2957945, better than mine.  Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Bump. If you don't, I'll edit my question, since your answer deserves to be rescued from the comments.

Comment: please go ahead Ben