# How to select part of a tensor (multidimensional array) with a vector of dimension names?

Tags: r, arrays, tensor

During a project in R I met this problem and I am really confused:

For example, I have a tensor T (dimension 3x2x2) and a vector A

```
T <- array(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), dim=c(3,2,2), dimnames=list(c("X","Y","Z"),c("1","2"),c("a","b")))
A <- c(NA, "2","b")
```

I'm wondering how can I get `T[ ,"2","b"]` with the use of vector `A`? I tried `T[A]` as long as many other things but it doesn't seem to work. Note that `A` is a variable and it could very well become `A <- c(NA, NA,"a")` and we would like to have  `T[ , ,"a"]` in this case.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I am not sure what you're seeking is possible by standard means in R. The first and simplest method is to create a list with arguments for the `[` function and use `do.call([, args)` (note missing hyphens for the bracket, due to markdown). But it this simply does not work: `v <- vector('list', 3); v[[3]] <- 'b'; do.call([, c(list(T), v)))` returns an empty matrix (again noting the lack of hyphens for the sharp bracket). The only way seems to be to include the indices for the missing dimensions as well, which leaves this highly impractical and memory inefficient.

Comment: Have also a look at: [Subset an array using a vector of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53013962/10488504)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (a little convoluted):

```
A2<-as.list(A)
A2[is.na(A)]<-TRUE
do.call(`[`,c(list(T),A2))
# X  Y  Z 
#10 11 12
```