Dynamically access array dimension
is there a way to dynamically access an array dimension (ideally without reshaping)?
I have an n-dimensional array arr as well as a named order of dimensions vals.
Both the number of dimensions for arr and the order of vals may change. I always want to access the first entry of arr for the dimension where vals equals B.
In the following I have provided three examples demonstrating what I want:
#Example 1
vals = c("A","B","C")
idx = grep("B",vals)
arr = array(runif(5^3), dim = c(5,5,5))

arr[,1,] # B is in second dimension

#Example 2
vals = c("A","C","B","D")
idx = grep("B",vals)
arr = array(runif(5^4), dim = c(5,5,5,5))

arr[,,1,] #B is in third dimension

#Example 3
vals = c("B","A","C","D","E")
idx = grep("B",vals)
arr = array(runif(5^5), dim = c(5,5,5,5,5))

arr[1,,,,] #B is in first dimension

I'm absolutely clueless how to approach this.

possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013962/subset-an-array-using-a-vector-of-indices

I think the simplest way is using asplit (but seems not as efficient as eval approach)
asplit(arr, idx)[[1]]

Other options

You can also try apply like below
array(apply(arr, idx, c)[, 1], dim(arr)[-idx])

and verify it, for example
> set.seed(0)

> vals <- c("B", "A", "C", "D", "E")

> idx <- grep("B", vals)

> arr <- array(runif(5^5), dim = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5))

> a <- arr[1, , , , ] # B is in first dimension

> b <- array(apply(arr, idx, c)[, 1], dim(arr)[-idx])

> all.equal(a, b)
[1] TRUE


If you are bothered by apply and its indexing logic, you can parse the string like
b <- eval(str2lang(sprintf("arr[%s]", toString(replace(rep("", length(dim(arr))), idx, "1")))))

and you can obtain
> all.equal(a, b)
[1] TRUE


asplit is very concise but the eval solution here seems to run faster.

@G.Grothendieck yes, I am aware of that too, even though the expression string might be long :)

something like this (using vals and arr from your example)?

    the_letter <- 'B'
    
    
    picklist <- Map(vals, f = \(val) ifelse(val == the_letter, 1, TRUE))
    do.call(`[`, c(list(x = arr), picklist))



1) apply Use apply over the indexes that do not correspond to B taking the first of each.  This is concise, does not involve explicit reshaping and uses only base R.
apply(arr, which(vals != "B"), head, 1)

Tests
set.seed(123)
vals = c("A","B","C")
arr = array(runif(5^3), dim = c(5,5,5))
identical(apply(arr, which(vals != "B"), head, 1), arr[,1,])
## [1] TRUE

set.seed(123)
vals = c("A","C","B","D")
arr = array(runif(5^4), dim = c(5,5,5,5))
identical(apply(arr, which(vals != "B"), head, 1), arr[,,1,])
## [1] TRUE

set.seed(123)
vals = c("B","A","C","D","E")
arr = array(runif(5^5), dim = c(5,5,5,5,5))
identical(apply(arr, which(vals != "B"), head, 1), arr[1,,,,])
## [1] TRUE

2) extract_dim The listarrays package has a function to do this.
library(listarrays)
extract_dim(arr, which(vals == "B"), 1)

Tests
library(listarrays)

set.seed(123)
vals = c("A","B","C")
arr = array(runif(5^3), dim = c(5,5,5))
identical(extract_dim(arr, which(vals == "B"), 1) , arr[,1,])
## [1] TRUE

set.seed(123)
vals = c("A","C","B","D")
arr = array(runif(5^4), dim = c(5,5,5,5))
identical(extract_dim(arr, which(vals == "B"), 1), arr[,,1,])
## [1] TRUE

set.seed(123)
vals = c("B","A","C","D","E")
arr = array(runif(5^5), dim = c(5,5,5,5,5))
identical(extract_dim(arr, which(vals == "B"), 1), arr[1,,,,])
## [1] TRUE

3) aperm If we knew that arr has at most 5 dimensions we could make each number of dimensions a separate case.  Extend to the maximum if there can be more than 5.  This only uses base R.
get_dim <- function(arr, vals, val = "B", i = 1) {
  a <- aperm(arr, order(vals != val))
  switch(length(dim(arr)), a[i], a[i,], a[i,,], a[i,,,], a[i,,,,], a[i,,,,,])
}

set.seed(123)
vals = c("A","B","C")
arr = array(runif(5^3), dim = c(5,5,5))
identical(get_dim(arr, vals) , arr[,1,])
## [1] TRUE

set.seed(123)
vals = c("A","C","B","D")
arr = array(runif(5^4), dim = c(5,5,5,5))
identical(get_dim(arr, vals), arr[,,1,])
## [1] TRUE

set.seed(123)
vals = c("B","A","C","D","E")
arr = array(runif(5^5), dim = c(5,5,5,5,5))
identical(get_dim(arr, vals), arr[1,,,,])
## [1] TRUE


You can create a text and evaluate it:
e.g.
cmd <- sprintf("arr[%s]", paste(ifelse(vals == "B", "1", ""), collapse = ","))
cmd
[1] "arr[,1,]"

eval(parse(text = cmd))


Ahh, thanks! I've tried eval() before but I think that I used it wrongly (without the parse() function).

With do.call:
do.call(`[`, c(list(arr), replace(as.list(rep(TRUE, length(dim(arr)))),
                                    grep("B", vals), 1)))

#Example 1
vals = c("A","B","C")
idx = grep("B",vals)
arr = array(runif(5^3), dim = c(5,5,5))
identical(
  do.call(`[`, c(list(arr), replace(as.list(rep(TRUE, length(dim(arr)))),
                                    grep("B", vals), 1))),
  arr[,1,] # B is in second dimension
)
#> [1] TRUE


#Example 2
vals = c("A","C","B","D")
idx = grep("B",vals)
arr = array(runif(5^4), dim = c(5,5,5,5))
identical(
  do.call(`[`, c(list(arr), replace(as.list(rep(TRUE, length(dim(arr)))),
                                    grep("B", vals), 1))),
  arr[,,1,] #B is in third dimension
)
#> [1] TRUE

#Example 3
vals = c("B","A","C","D","E")
idx = grep("B",vals)
arr = array(runif(5^5), dim = c(5,5,5,5,5))
identical(
  do.call(`[`, c(list(arr), replace(as.list(rep(TRUE, length(dim(arr)))),
                                    grep("B", vals), 1))),
  arr[1,,,,] #B is in first dimension
)
#> [1] TRUE

